# How to change the text on certain condition in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to change the text/value of a cell in certain condition in GridView. I have a cell that return 'P', 'A', 'R' when I bind the Gridview from database. I want to show 'Pending' in case of 'P', 'Approved' in case of 'A' and 'Rejected' in case of 'R' in the dropdown with the update button. I want to change the status of a record.

How can I change the text AND do my required task at the time of Binding of data.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn> 
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="bgB white p5 b treb ttu w10" />
  <HeaderTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text="Status"></asp:Label>       
  </HeaderTemplate> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblrmastatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RMA_STATUS") %>'>
    </asp:Label> 
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: <asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="bgB white p5 b treb ttu w10" />
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text="Status"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblrmastatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RMA_STATUS") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

Comment: When providing code, do it as an edit, not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am new on this website.

Comment: Hello Anders, can u please help me on this?

Comment: What do you want to show in the DropDown? I guess you want to show the current status as a long text instead of the first letter in a Label and the other status values in a DropDown so that you can set a new status. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is to handle the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. It is raised once per row (also header and footer rows, so you need to filter for rows of type `DataRow`). You can use it to adjust the data that are displayed or the way they are displayed. Also you can set the values of a DropDown in the event. See the link for a sample.

In order to add the DropDown-column to the GridView, use a [TemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and put the DropDown into the ItemTemplate. Access the corresponding cell in the RowDataBound event handler. Use the FindControl method to retrieve the DropDown control and set its values.

---

The following sample shows how to set the Label and the DropDownList programmatically:

### GridView

The GridView shows both the original status and a new status with the long text, a DropDownList and a command column to update the data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdv" runat="server" 
              OnRowDataBound="gdv_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RMAStatus" HeaderText="Original RMA Status" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adjusted RMA Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Code-behind

In Code-behind, I've defined a class called `DataClass` that contains the data (you can also use a DataTable, but for the sample it was easier to use a class to generate some data). Also, a dictionary contains the mappings from the short status to the long text.

In `Page_Load`, the dictionary is set up and if it is no PostBack, the data are bound.

Finally, in `gdv_RowDataBound`, the label is set for each row and the DropDownList is initialized. Please note that the Label and the DropDownList for the row are retrieved by using `FindControl`.

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string RMAStatus { get; set; }
}

private readonly Dictionary<string, string> rmaStatusMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rmaStatusMappings.Add("R", "Rejected");
    rmaStatusMappings.Add("A", "Approved");
    rmaStatusMappings.Add("P", "Pending");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var data = new DataClass[] {
            new DataClass() { RMAStatus = "P" }, 
            new DataClass() { RMAStatus = "A" }, 
            new DataClass() { RMAStatus = "R" }, 
            new DataClass() { RMAStatus = "P" }, 
        };
        gdv.DataSource = data;
        gdv.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gdv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var rowStatus = ((DataClass)e.Row.DataItem).RMAStatus;
        // Set label to long status
        var lblStatus = e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblStatus") as Label;
        if (lblStatus != null)
            lblStatus.Text = rmaStatusMappings[rowStatus];
        // Set drop down items
        var ddlStatus = e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
        if (ddlStatus != null)
        {
            ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddlStatus.DataSource = rmaStatusMappings;
            ddlStatus.DataBind();
            ddlStatus.SelectedValue = rowStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know in the comments if you have any questions.