# How can I change the value at the time of binding the data from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to change the text/value of a cell in certain condition in GridView.

I have a cell that return 'P', 'A', 'R' when I bind the Gridview from database.
 I want to show the

```
'Pending' in case of 'P',
'Approved' in case of 'A' and 
'Rejected' in case of 'R'
```

How can I change the value at the time of binding the data from database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the text on certain condition in GridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266111/how-to-change-the-text-on-certain-condition-in-gridview)

Comment: Don't post the same question several times.

Comment: <asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="bgB white p5 b treb ttu w10" />
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text="Status"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblrmastatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RMA_STATUS") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

This is the code which I used to bind the cell & in code behind I am binding Grid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select (case when name='p'  then 'pending' when name='A' then 'Approved' else 'rejected' end) as a from dbo.student

name is your columnname
student is table name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq to dataTable.

Just store dataTable which come for your GridView datasource, and apply your changes with logic queries, which going to much easy and than assign it to GridView datasource...

Second we can solve bu handling onDataBound even, but first idea is much batter...

Problem will be solved....